# Problem in posting data in my table in .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a problem in my .NET Web API - I am just posting data in my table before I am checking Is the record already inserted in the table but I get this error:

> An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/tblProducts/AddToWishCart", Name = "GetAddWishCartList")]
public IHttpActionResult AddToWishCart(tblWishCart3 wishList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    IEnumerable<GetAllCartListByStatusAndUserPrdIdWeightId_Result> tblCartWishList = dbO.GetAllCartListByStatusAndUserPrdIdWeightId(wishList.Status, wishList.UserId, wishList.PrdId, wishList.Extra3).AsEnumerable();

    if (tblCartWishList == null)
    {
        var AltAddress = dbO.AddWishCart4(wishList.UserId, wishList.PrdId, wishList.Name, wishList.Weight, wishList.MRP, wishList.SellingPrice, wishList.OffPerentage, wishList.Quantity, wishList.Status, wishList.AddDate, wishList.Pic1, wishList.Extra1, wishList.Extra2, wishList.Extra3, wishList.Extra4, wishList.Extra5, wishList.Extra6, wishList.Extra7, wishList.Extra8, wishList.Extra9, wishList.Extra10);
    }
    else
    {
    }
  
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetAddWishCartList", new { id = wishList.UserId }, wishList);
}
```

Comment: Where is the inner exception?

Comment: This is inner ExceptionMessage: "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."

Comment: Where do you get this error at? Probably at `AddWishCart4`. And what do you do in the `AddWishCart4` method?

Comment: i am just adding a new record in the table from addwishCart4 and checking the record is present in the table or not from GetAllCartListByStatusAndUserPrdIdWeightId but facing this error

Comment: I Solve this error by adding  .ToArray() in dbO.GetAllCartListByStatusAndUserPrdIdWeightId(wishList.Status, wishList.UserId, wishList.PrdId, wishList.Extra3).AsEnumerable(); but i am facing one more problem it is not going on if condition although it is getting in tblCartWishList

Comment: Basically i want check my IEnumerable is empty or not

Comment: What do you want to do if `tblCartWishList` is not null? Do you get any errors if not null?

Comment: if cart is not null then don't add any record and i am not getting any error but it is not working(Inserting Record) while table is empty